# WSO2ESB Custom Mediator Java Class is not found in the path

Tags: wso2-esb

I have created the project using WSO2 Developer Studio.
Under `src/main/java` I created the package `samples.mediators`
In that package the class `UnzipFileMediator`:

```
package samples.mediators;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext; 
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class UnzipFileMediator extends AbstractMediator {
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) { 
        // TODO Implement your mediation logic here 
        System.out.println("UnzipFile Mediation entered");
        return true;
    }
}
```

To deploy the code an followed this instructions:

1. Right click on the project and select Export Project as Deployable Archive.
2. It created the jar file named Unzip.jar
3. I deployed the Jar file in to `<ESB_HOME>/repository/components/lib` 
   directory.

In the synapse configuration I call the class like this

```
<class name="samples.mediators.UnzipFileMediator"></class>
```

but when i try to save it.It generate the below error:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Class samples.mediators.UnzipFileMediator not found in the path

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use a different package name**.

Because the namespace (or package) `samples.mediators` is already used by WSO2 in a different jar. You had deployed now a second jar with the same package name, these classes will not be found in the Classpath by WSO2.

Choose for your own classes a correct package (namespace) with your company name like `com.mycompany.mediators`.